# Strange logs in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

I ran `sudo lsof -i :80` on port 80 to check what is port 80 listening to   and I got the output bellow.

I dont understand what this means. It seems like some program is running on our server and using tor exit nodes.

How do I kill this malicious program?

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 5372     root    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5375 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5375 www-data   12u  IPv6  52941      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54796 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5376 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5376 www-data   12u  IPv6  52939      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54734 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5377 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5377 www-data   12u  IPv6  52938      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54732 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5378 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5378 www-data   12u  IPv6  52940      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54738 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5379 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5379 www-data   12u  IPv6  52942      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54908 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5382 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5382 www-data   12u  IPv6  52956      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54942 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5383 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5383 www-data   12u  IPv6  52958      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54976 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5384 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5384 www-data   12u  IPv6  52957      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54940 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5385 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5385 www-data   12u  IPv6  52962      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54994 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5386 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5386 www-data   12u  IPv6  52961      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54992 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5387 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5387 www-data   12u  IPv6  52960      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54996 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5388 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5388 www-data   12u  IPv6  52959      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:54998 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5389 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5389 www-data   12u  IPv6  52968      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:26567 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5390 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5390 www-data   12u  IPv6  52966      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55104 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5391 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5391 www-data   12u  IPv6  52964      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55094 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5392 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5392 www-data   12u  IPv6  52963      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55054 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5393 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5393 www-data   12u  IPv6  52965      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55102 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5394 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5394 www-data   12u  IPv6  52969      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:26568 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5395 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5395 www-data   12u  IPv6  53110      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:31376 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5396 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5396 www-data   12u  IPv6  52970      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:26645 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5397 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5397 www-data   12u  IPv6  52981      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55274 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5398 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5398 www-data   12u  IPv6  52976      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55222 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5399 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5399 www-data   12u  IPv6  52975      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55220 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5400 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5400 www-data   12u  IPv6  52974      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:26789 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5401 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5401 www-data   12u  IPv6  52973      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55182 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5402 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5402 www-data   12u  IPv6  52977      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55224 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5403 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5403 www-data   12u  IPv6  52979      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55256 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5404 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5404 www-data   12u  IPv6  52978      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55252 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5405 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5405 www-data   12u  IPv6  52980      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55254 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5406 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5406 www-data   12u  IPv6  52984      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55276 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5407 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5407 www-data   12u  IPv6  52982      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:26913 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5408 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5408 www-data   12u  IPv6  52983      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55272 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5409 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5409 www-data   12u  IPv6  52985      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55322 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5410 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5410 www-data   12u  IPv6  52987      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:27036 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5411 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5411 www-data   12u  IPv6  52986      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55320 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5412 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5412 www-data   12u  IPv6  52988      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55344 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5413 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5413 www-data   12u  IPv6  53002      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55418 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5414 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5414 www-data   12u  IPv6  52997      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55376 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5415 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5415 www-data   12u  IPv6  52996      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55342 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5416 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5416 www-data   12u  IPv6  52999      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55372 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5417 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5417 www-data   12u  IPv6  53001      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55420 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5418 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5418 www-data   12u  IPv6  52998      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55374 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5419 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5419 www-data   12u  IPv6  53000      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55408 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5420 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5420 www-data   12u  IPv6  53003      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:55422 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5421 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5421 www-data   12u  IPv6  53004      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:27391 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5422 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5422 www-data   12u  IPv6  53007      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:27573 (ESTABLISHED)                                                                                      ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56150 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5462 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5462 www-data   12u  IPv6  53045      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:64248 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5463 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5463 www-data   12u  IPv6  53046      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:19251 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5464 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5464 www-data   12u  IPv6  53048      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29429 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5465 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5465 www-data   12u  IPv6  53047      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29430 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5466 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5466 www-data   12u  IPv6  53050      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29501 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5467 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5467 www-data   12u  IPv6  53051      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29531 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5468 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5468 www-data   12u  IPv6  53049      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29471 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5469 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5469 www-data   12u  IPv6  53052      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56268 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5470 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5470 www-data   12u  IPv6  53053      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56266 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5471 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5471 www-data   12u  IPv6  53054      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56276 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5472 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5472 www-data   12u  IPv6  53055      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29649 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5473 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5473 www-data   12u  IPv6  53056      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29694 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5474 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5474 www-data   12u  IPv6  53057      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:29692 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5475 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5475 www-data   12u  IPv6  53058      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56314 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5476 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5476 www-data   12u  IPv6  53059      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56316 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5477 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5477 www-data   12u  IPv6  53063      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        
apache2 5488 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5488 www-data   12u  IPv6  53071      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56476 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5489 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5489 www-data   12u  IPv6  53075      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30309 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5490 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5490 www-data   12u  IPv6  53072      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56474 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5491 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5491 www-data   12u  IPv6  53073      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56518 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5492 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5492 www-data   12u  IPv6  53074      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56568 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5493 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5493 www-data   12u  IPv6  53077      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30412 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5494 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5494 www-data   12u  IPv6  53076      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56628 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5495 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5495 www-data   12u  IPv6  53078      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56676 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5496 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5496 www-data   12u  IPv6  53080      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30559 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5497 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5497 www-data   12u  IPv6  53079      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->exit4.tor-network.net:56678 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5498 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5498 www-data   12u  IPv6  53081      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30572 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5499 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5499 www-data   12u  IPv6  53082      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30595 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5500 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5500 www-data   12u  IPv6  53084      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:30596 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 5526 www-data    4u  IPv6  52924      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5526 www-data   12u  IPv6  53109      0t0  TCP 207.246.94.76.vultr.com:h                                                                                        ttp->tor-exit-anonymizer-10.appliedprivacy.net:31386 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the apache web server?

Comment: So bad.Its not logs, what it means? You check lsof man page.

Comment: So bad.Its not logs, what it means? You check lsof man page.

Comment: You "remove this program" by completely nuking the server.

Comment: Is "your server" a webserver? If yes, `apache2` is the application to make it a webserver, so what you see are lots of apache-processes serving your web pages.

Comment: Please ensure you have authority to interact with this server, inspect the change logs of the server and ensure the apache2 server is supposed to be running on this server. Maybe you should check what this server is, navigate to `http://<server_ip>`

Answer (score 3):

The first field in the output of your `lsof` command shows that `apache2` is the “malicious” program listening on Port 80. Apache listens and waits for connections on Port 80 (by default from anywhere); it doesn’t initiate them. You haven’t given much background information about your server setup and without any context, the `lsof` output looks like you’re simply running a web server and somebody is using Tor to connect to it. I personally maintain a number of web servers and I generally don’t care where the client is connecting from.

If you want to know more about the connections from the Tor client, you should check the Apache log files. If you didn’t actually install Apache, then you’ve *big* problems and have to [deal with a compromised server](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/190981).